# Should Boost Bjam/b2 fail when darwin.jam's macosx-version-min is set to a SDK version not installed on my machine?

Tags: ios, boost, bjam

I am building some C++ Boost libs (test library) for iOS. I would like set the b2's macosx-version-min option to a SDK version not installed on my machine (eg: macosx-version-min = 4.3 while only SDK 6.0 is installed). However, Boost's b2 reports an error stating that there is no SDK installed with the request version.

- a) Should be Boost Bjam/b2 fail when b2's macosx-version-min is set to a SDK version not installed on my machine ?
- b) Since Boost libraries are C++ libraries, does it make sense to specify a macosx-version-min (aka Deployement Target SDK on iOS) ?
- c) If yes to b), what scenario would it be useful for ? I know it useful in Objective-C when weak linking Apple's frameworks header symbols.

Computer settings:

- Max OS X 10.8.2
- iOS SDK installed: iOS 6.0
- Xcode: 4.5.2
- Boost C++: 1.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in boot's jam files that they have not fixed yet..  I hacked the jam files before to "add" in the min ver I want..    I really do hope they switch to cmake REALLY soon as CMake properly understands this.

So, to do this edit the tools/build/v2/tools/darwin.jam file and add this line

```
feature.extend macosx-version-min : 4.3 ;
```

after the

```
feature macosx-version-min : : propagated optional ;
```

line.

This also works for Mac OS X as well.. e.g. adding in 10.6 to the min version list.